# PHPSECLIB Read() with multiple strings

Tags: phpseclib

I am working with a ancient IBM box with a weird GUI. I would like to do something like:

```
read ("ENTER NUMBER" || "WARNING NO NUMBERS AVAILABLE");
```

Where it will scan for either of those 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 1.0 this should do the trick:

```
$ssh->read('#ENTER NUMBER|WARNING NO NUMBERS AVAILABLE#', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX)
```

If you're using 2.0 this should do the trick:

```
$ssh->read('#ENTER NUMBER|WARNING NO NUMBERS AVAILABLE#', SSH2::READ_REGEX)
```